# Menu and other theme elements displaying weird in applications (e.g. Terminal, Settings) on upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, menu

I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 17.10 and now my terminal menus look like this:

[image: Messed up terminal menus]

I don't know if this is related or not but additionally, when I go into my system settings to change anything, some of the widgets don't seem to have loaded correctly:

[image: Settings]

I click on "ON" or "OFF" for any of those settings and nothing changes. Some things work, like I was able to change my display resolution, but most things don't.

Any ideas what's gone wrong and how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the GTK+ theme you are using somehow got corrupted or is unsupported by the newer version.

To change the theme first install *(GNOME) Tweaks* by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then open Tweaks and go to "*Appearance*" section. Select a different theme for "*Applications*" under **Themes**.